# ElementTree write method

Tags: python, xml, elementtree

I am trying to write some XML to disk:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

root = ET.Element("root")
doc = ET.SubElement(root, "doc")

ET.SubElement(doc, "field1", name="blah").text = "some value1"
ET.SubElement(doc, "field2", name="asdfasd").text = "some vlaue2"

ET.dump(root)
ET.write("filename.xml")
```

However I get the error `AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'write'`

I can't figure out what module has the `write` attribute. All the examples I've seen online show the attribute as belonging to `tree`, but I don't know how to define `tree`. One source does this:

```
from xml.etree.ElementTree import ElementTree
tree = ElementTree()
tree.parse("index.xhtml")
tree.write("output.xhtml")
```

But I am not reading and parsing a file. Would appreciate some help, thanks.

Comment: you can always do `open('filename.xml', 'w').write(ET.dump(root))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need

```
tree = ET.ElementTree(root)
tree.write("filename.xml")
```

You can also use

```
open('filename.xml', 'w').write(ET.dump(root))
```